# Laravel selectize.js result is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, select, selectize.js

I am using [Selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) for tags, Which is coming from DB via ajax get request.

In my controller :

```
$tags = Tag::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->get('query'))->pluck('name', 'id');
$prep_tags = [];
foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
    $prep_tags['name'] = $value;
}
return response()->json([
    'name' => $prep_tags
]);
```

Ajax success :

```
success: function(res) {
    console.log(res.name);
    callback(res.name);
}
```

On correct search, Console.log(res.name) shows :

`{name: "Jeep"}`

Selectize.js JS code :

```
$("#new-addTag-selectize").selectize({
valueField: 'name',
labelField: 'name',
searchField: ['name'],
plugins: ['remove_button'],
persist: false,
createOnBlur: true,
create: true,
load: function(query, callback) {
$.ajax({
  url: '/get/tags/',
  data: { query: query},
  dataType: "json",
  type: 'GET',
  error: function() {
    callback();
  },
  success: function(res) {
    callback(res.name);
  } 
})
}
});
```

But the autocomplete is not working. 
What am i missing ?

Comment: Can you show your selectize code as well? Also One thing that I see though is that in your `foreach` you are overwriting the "name" key on each iteration. Is that what you really want to do there?

Comment: @codisfy question updates, added js code, Plus i want the result to be shown in autocomplete, I am not very sure about the foreach.

Comment: Where is this `callback` defined?

Comment: @codisfy in ajax success. `callback(res.name)`

Comment: Oh missed that.. can you try sending just `res` to the callback? Instead of res.name

Comment: @codisfy still not working

Comment: From what I can see here http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ . Looks like res should be an array. So just for quick try you can either pass `[res]` to callback on javascript. Or in your PHP code wrap the array within another array(although I am highly doubtful about your PHP code but let's take that up later)

Comment: @codisfy Can you make it an answer ?

Comment: Will surely add it. Did it work?

Comment: Not yet, Will try your answer too. Waiting for it

Comment: I have created a pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqXmzb?page=1& . You can get the idea there. Check comments on the JS code. If it works for you will add it as an answer

Comment: @codisfy And the controller method code, Will it work with mine ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the things apart from the code above is working here your PHP code should be :

```
$tags = Tag::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->get('query'))->pluck('name', 'id');
$prep_tags = [];
foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
    $prep_tags[]= ['name' =>  $value];
}
return response()->json($prep_tags);
```

this is to make $prep_tags of form:

```
    $prep_tags = [
      ['name' => 'value1'], 
      ['name' => 'value2']
    ];
```

then in your JS success should be :

```
success: function(res) {
    callback(res);
  }
```

assuming that when you `console.log(res)` you see `[{"name":"value1"}, {"name":"value2"}]` it should work.